# Unable to Locate element using xpath in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am new in Python and I am having problem with my Code. I am trying web scrape using Selenium by xpath, but when I run my code it shows an error such as `"Unable to Locate element using: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="T1"]"}`. Tried using ID and Name as the element, but still not working.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from getpass import getpass
import time
    
username1 = input("Username:")
username2 = input("Username2:")
password = getpass("Password")
stock = input("Stock Name:")
   
driver = webdriver.Chrome("")
driver.get("")
   
time.sleep(10)
username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("txtUser1")
username_textbox.send_keys('username1')
   
username1_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("txtUser2")
username1_textbox.send_keys('username2')
    
password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("txtPassword")
password_textbox.send_keys('password')
password_textbox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
time.sleep(10)
    
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="T1"]')
search.send_keys('stock')
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Element from Inspection View of the site.

`<input type="text" id="T1" name="T1" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {document.getElementById('B1').click()}" size="8" value="" style="font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 8pt; color: #424542">"`

Error Message
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="T1"]"} (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.135)`

Comment: I edited my post so that you can see the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try waiting for the website to load.
The code below is taken from the [selenium python docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#:%7E:text=WebDriverWait%20in%20combination%20with%20ExpectedCondition%20is%20one%20way%20this%20can%20be%20accomplished.&text=This%20waits%20up%20to%2010,milliseconds%20until%20it%20returns%20successfully.)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="T1"]"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried the time.sleep and the above code, but still same issue.